# How can I loadChildren in my Routes when my module is on some CDN

Tags: angular, angular-router

Ok, so I want to publish my prebuilt angular module on some cdn, and then let some angular route be able to point to it and have it loaded.

I haven't stepped the angular code yet, but there is probably a good reason I can't simply point the loadChildren to some random url and expect it to fetch and load the module.  If you look at my code example, the only piece the works is when I have my prebuilt goo.umd.js module in the same directory as my index.html file.

I have yet to find any example of a CustomLoader that will pull this module from my rawgit.com CDN.  Any direction on where I can focus my research would be appreciated.

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
declare var System: any; 
let gooUrl = "https://rawgit.com/ghstahl/angular4-goo-module/master/dist/bundles/goo.umd.js#GooModule";
let badGooUrl = "https://idontexist.com/ghstahl/angular4-goo-module/master/dist/bundles/goo.umd.js#GooModule";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'goo',     loadChildren: () => System.import(gooUrl)}, // doesn't work, and this url exists.
  { path: 'goo-bad',     loadChildren: () => System.import(badGooUrl)},// doesn't work, as I expected a 404.
  { path: 'goo-url',     loadChildren: gooUrl}, // doesn't work, and this url exists.
  { path: 'goo-local',     loadChildren: "goo.umd.js#GooModule"} // works
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a link to your module in the SystemJS config file:

```
'myModule': 'https://rawgit.com/ghstahl/angular4-goo-module/master/dist/bundles/goo.umd.js'
```

Then, you can load it like:

```
loadChildren: "myModule#GooModule"
```

See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/CTnNMszU236YfWxnuqHk?p=preview) that illustrates this.

Comment: Nice, next issue: What if I don't know the url to myModule up front and in reality will never know it.  Imagine that backend sends me an array of the following [{path:'blah', url:'http://a.com/blah.bundle.js'}]

Comment: If all of your modules are on the same domain, you can do like this:
```'myModule': 'https://rawgit.com/ghstahl/angular4-goo-module/master/dist/bundles'```

```loadChildren: "myModule/goo.umd.js#GooModule"```

Comment: Thanks Gosha, unfortunately they aren't.  What is expected is that the hosting angular app can fetch modules from anywhere.  My rawgit.com domain is to test this.  I have been able to do this with a React/Mobx project where my so-called bundled module gets injected into the DOM-HEAD as a script and when it runs it advertises its routes to the host.

Comment: Why do you need this at all?

Comment: 1. I have teams that insists on using angular2, and it isn't worth fighting  even if the react version is working. 2. I have external teams that insist that their bundles need to be on their severs and are not willing to put said bundles under my domain.  The joys of large enterprise teams, where I am lucky enough to get them to even agree on a single framework.  In practice this actually works where you allow different teams full control over their delivery and as the host, I am not building a monolith app.  I am building a host app that loads plugins.

Comment: Thank you, @HerbStahl. I discovered that `loadChildren: "https://rawgit.com/ghstahl/angular4-goo-module/master/dist/bundles/goo.umd.js#GooModule"` works without additional configuration. See https://plnkr.co/edit/0crJ8ZBiZpWoLvk78aiH?p=preview. Are you sure that this does not work for you? If it does not, modify my sample to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I was using the latest Tour or Heros as a starting point, and with no change to the angular teams demo, I added this the gooUrl route and got errors only when going to the rawgit url.  No errors when my goo.bundle.js was under my domain.  Perhaps it is how they are building.  I will start another question as to that error that I was seeing.  Thank you for proving this works.