# How to loadchildren dynamically from different server or CDN (runtime) using Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

How can I load lazy module (loadchildren) on server `A` from server`B`?
I've searched a couple of links from google but, I can't find the correct answer with an example.

I've found this [How can I loadChildren in my Routes when my module is on some CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108316/how-can-i-loadchildren-in-my-routes-when-my-module-is-on-some-cdn)
 which could be similar to my question but I didn't understand the example of it and the answer seems incomplete for me.

**My questions are:**

1. Do I need to compile the whole project including lazy modules?
2. Can I compile lazy module only and refer to the main module via `loadchildren`?
3. How can I make bundles of separated main & lazy module project?
4. If I separate the main project & lazy module, should I include `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(FirstLazyModule )` on lazy module too?

My requirement is make a bundle of lazy module using webpack/angular and host it to server `B` while the main bootstrap module is hosted on server `A` where I can give a lazy module link to the `Routes` of main (bootstrapper) module property of `loadchildren` at runtime.

*Note*: I don't want to compile whole project with lazy modules and host chunks to different server.

**Example**

App route with no knowledge of lazy module but CDN link only.

```
// http links to load lazy modules from server B
const m1Link = 'http link of M1 which hosted on server B'
const m2Link = 'http link of M2 which hosted on server B'

const route:Routes = [
     { path:'M1', loadchildren: m1Link, canActive: m1Fn() },
     { path:'M2', loadchildren: m2Link, canActive: m2Fn() }
]
```

Lazy module

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: DefaultComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: LazyChildComponent}]
}];

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports:      [ RouterModule ],
    declarations: [ LazyChildComponent ]
})
export class FirstLazyModule { }
```