# Angular Module to Import Dynamically another Angular Module bundled at s3 at runtime

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, angular7, angular-module

I have a **Angular 7 project** which is deployed at server X. Basically, this App is a **Container Type Application** which should **load other Angular Modules**.

Server side Angular project ***doesn't*** have the **children Module** related *definition/information* except the cdn url of the angular module to be loaded.

I've tried multiple approaches to achieve this

--> Bundled the Children Module files as SystemJs Modules and tried to import it in the Parent Module using `System.import` and `SystemNgModuleLoader` too

--> Exported the Children Modules as UMD and tried to execute it on the Parent Module, then tried loading using the System

however i wasn't able to achieve the said functionality.

Is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: isn't it a CORS issue ?

Comment: @Tuckbros It is handled properly on the client. So not an issue.

Comment: Can this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108316/how-can-i-loadchildren-in-my-routes-when-my-module-is-on-some-cdn?noredirect=1&lq=1 help you ?

Comment: @KevinFONTAINE Thank you for the help! But Unfortunately It doesn't work anymore with Angular version > 6 :(

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if what you are trying to do would be possible.

One option can be for you to use iframes so the content from  app2 gets rendered within the app1's iframe container. But that wouldn't be just module loading, but instead a page load within the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but loading it in iframe doesn't solve the use-case as the inter module communication breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the CORS setup [here](https://medium.com/@bevin.hernandez/angular-5-file-uploads-to-s3-with-relative-ease-ea19b7fd120e)
Also take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395048/2825392)?
it looks quite similar to what you are trying to achieve